# Is it possible to get and use autosigned certificates?

Tags: java-me

To sign a java-me application I want to get and use auto-signed certificates. Is it possible ? And where to get them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Its not possile on Java-Me. Better you can buy from some 3rd party providers.
Signing providers are,

[Thawte](http://www.thawte.com/code-signing/content-signing-certificates/sun-java/index.html)

[Verisign](https://www.verisign.com/code-signing/sun-java/index.html?sl=productdetails)

[Java Verified](http://javaverified.com/)